# How to lower an image vertically on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been defeated attempting to figure out how to lower an image on a website.
I have seen lots of people simply doing .img {...} and editing it that way, the problem is that I have more than one img that is using that tag so if I edit it that way, it will affect all tags that utilize it, which is not what I want. Simply put, I have an image that is displaying near the top of my website and I would simply want it lower. For the class, here is the code:

```
.bichon{
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 850px;
}
```

for my class and then for the image insert:

```
<img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/93/Bichon_Fris%C3%A9_-_studdogbichon.jpg/1200px-Bichon_Fris%C3%A9_-_studdogbichon.jpg" class = "bichon">
```

The image is centered horizontally but I simply want to lower it a bit vertically so it's not overshadowing my navigation bar.
Thanks.

Comment: I am guessing that you need margin-top: 50px. You can change 50px depending on how much you want to lower the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
.bichon {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    height: 300px;
    width: 850px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a margin at the top. This will lower your image. I suggest make margin-top equal to the height of your navigation bar.

```
.bichon{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 80px; //the height of your navigation bar
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 850px;
```

}